# Dismiss view controller, go to tab-bar view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I have 4 pages on startup. They are all view controllers. I also have a tab-bar controller with 4 views/tabbar-items. I want a button on the 4 view controller pages that links to the correct tab-bar view. For example, if I am on the third view controller, I want to get to the third view in the tab-bar. 
I've tried to use the

`[((UITabBarController *)(self.parentViewController))setSelectedIndex:index];`

method. But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do these "4 pages" relate to your tab bar controller? Are they the controllers embedded in the tab bar controller? It sounds like not, from what you'r trying to do, so where are they in your view controller hierarchy?

Comment: Well, they take place in the AppDelegate. And to show my other views ontop of the tab-bar controller i use this code: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static BOOL first = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIViewController *popup = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];
        
        [self presentViewController:popup animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = NO;
    }
}

Comment: are you sure that the parentViewController is actually the UITabBarController you want?

Comment: This sounds like a strange setup. Where do you have that viewDidAppear code"? Is it in one (or each) of the controllers in the tab bar controller?

Comment: It's in one of the view controller, to launch that view before the tab-bar controller.